# QGIS style to DB

Tags: qgis, style, database

I want to import the style from a MapInfo.tab file into a postgis db.
When I open the properties for the file and click on the botton style I only have the option save as *QGIS QML style file* or *SLD style file* but I don´t have *save in Database*, like in the screenshot.

[image]

Where can I find the option?
I use the QGIS version 3.4.14

Answer (score 1):

Try `save/set as default`, the third option from the top when you click the `style`-dropdown. At least with Geopackage this saves the style directly where the datasource is.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
I found my mistake. I have to import the data to the database, then load this data, change the style and then I can import the style information to my database,too

Comment: Hi, answers aren't the place to ask new questions. Please post a new question for that. Thanks.